# How to get day of month from calender

Tags: java

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Date and Time: "+now.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"
                    +now.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"
                    +now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "
                    + now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                    + ":"
                    + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

It gives Output >>Date and Time : 2016-7-8 16:10

But I want >>Date and Time : 2016-8-8 16:10

Means it gives the day of month wrong,then how to rewrite above code for correct output.

Comment: It's not the day of month that is incorrect, but the month itself. Refer to the linked question for explanation.

Comment: Java Calendar api is indexed. Starts from 0 and ends with 11 so it's a correct output.

Comment: Thank you!! This  answer is useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not giving wrong output. In java's Calendar, months are zero indexed.

see the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH).

> MONTH
>
> public static final int MONTH
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year.

It means they're starting from 0 to 11.

> 0 - January
>   1 - February
>   2 - March
>   3 - April
>   4 - May
>   5 - June
>   6 - July
>   7 - August
>   8 - September
>   9 - October
>   10 - November
>   11 - December

... and so on

You can simply add 1 and get the code working for you.